# Generating a number from a drop down list in excel to use in a formula in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to assign a numerical value to three choices in a dropdown list to use in a formula. (Ex: Calendar = 12, Academic = 9, Summer = 3) but I want the text to be visible and not the number, but I want only the number component to be used in another cell's formula. Is this possible?

Comment: Use a lookup table and [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with index match. Essentially search for a word in a list, ad get the value associated to it. Like vlookup, but marginally more efficient. YOu will not likely notice it on small use cases, but if you get a lot of them in one notebook, you will notice a difference in performance over v lookup.

https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match

```
=INDEX(C3:E11,MATCH("Value",B3:B11,0),2)
```

Effectively says you have a collection of KVPs (Key value pairs) in B3-C11, get the value in B3-B11, and the index in the list it relates to, then get the value corresponding in C3-C11.

In the above example "Value" would be the cell you want to match that is a dropdown selection of the text value of the range, and the number would appear in the cell where you have this formula, giving you display in one, and value in the other.

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 3 values and not more you can also use custom number format.
In the 3 cells, let it be `E3:E5`, you enter values 12, 9, and 3. For each cell you use custom number format e.g. `"Calendar"` for 12, `"Academic"` for 9, `"Summer"` for 3.
In the cell `C3` you set your dropdown with a list in `E3:E5`.
Custom format here is more complex, because it must be conditional:
`[=3]"Summer";[=9]"Academic";"Calendar"`
Now you can use numeric values from C3 in any formula.
[image: Dropdown with text list and numeric result]

Comment: Neat and elegant, I like this!